# How to provide mapping information of xilinx primitives during yosys synthesis

Tags: xilinx, yosys

I am new to Yosys and I am trying to synthesize a design using xilinx primitives.
I want to know if we can synthesize a design using xilinx primitives. If yes,
then how do we provide the mapping information of these xilinx primitives during synthesis.

If someone can help me with an example, it would be really helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The `synth_xilinx` command provides synthesis for a number of Xilinx FPGAs (you can see more information running `yosys -h synth_xilinx`). As this pass has seen quite a bit of improvement in the last year or two, I'd strongly recommend using it on latest git master Yosys rather than any older releases.

Comment: Thanks for this information. I tried with this command and as per the command's documentation, it internally runs bram command which is failing in execution.

Comment: I am getting error messages like mapping to bram type failed

Comment: Can you provide the detailed failure output? Unless the execution actually stops, failure to map one particular BRAM type isn't necessarily a problem if another maps OK, or the memory isn't intended to be BRAM at all.

Comment: The problem was this 
bram:    (skip if '-nobram')
        memory_bram -rules +/xilinx/brams.txt
        techmap -map +/xilinx/brams_map.v
Since I was not giving any xilinx family in input while performing synthesis, bram mapping was failing. After adding the family (xcu) , I was able to obtain mapping.
Thanks a lot for your support.

Answer (score -1):

If ouy're interested in a rough estimate of the logic occupation in Xilinx primitive you could assume that only LUT4 (or LUT6) are used for the circuit and synthesize using the
LUT mapping feature present in yosis.
It actually uses **abc** to map. The command is something like:

```
lut 4:4
```

for more details : **yosis** and **help abc**

If you're interested in a real circuit deployable on a generic xilinx fpga, I'm not sure this is possible.